# Approximating a random field

Tags: modeling, stochastic-processes

I have got a bunch of $n$ ($\approx 100$) pixelized maps. Each pixel is a single figure. Each so-called map can be represented by a matrix whom each element is a pixel. Let's say that there $p\times p$ pixels.

All these pictures have been generated through the same process. Thus, I consider that each picture is a realization of one unique random field.

**I would like to approximate this random field thanks to the maps I already have, and to be able from the approximate random field to simulate more realizations.**

I do not know how to handle such a problem. The thoughts I have got on this problem are the following:

- I think I should first begin with a easier problem: approximating a stochastic process.
- I could begin by reducing the data dimension with principal component analysis or things like that...

Comment: There is a rich theory of modeling and simulating spatial stochastic processes. Perhaps the first thing to consider, for narrowing down the options, is the nature of each "pixel": what kinds of values can it have (real, positive, integral, binary?) and what exactly do they represent (cell averages? point values? cell maxima?).